# How to configure sentry to send exception from process spawned by python multiprocessing pools?

Tags: python, celery, python-multiprocessing, sentry

I have a script which is run by celery worker which uses Pool from billiard library and I spawned multiple process. I am trying to use sentry inside those process so that any unhandled/handled exception can be caught. Written below is my sample code :

```
from configurations import SENTRY_CLIENT


def process_data(data):
try:
    s = data/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print "Sentry must report this."
    SENTRY_CLIENT.captureException()

import multiprocessing
from billiard import Pool
POOL_SIZE=multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = Pool(POOL_SIZE)
data=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
pool.map(process_data, data)
pool.close()
pool.terminate()
```

SENTRY_CLIENT is defined in configuration file which is defined as :
configurations.py

```
from raven import Client
SENTRY_CLIENT = Client("dsn")
```

One way which I am trying is to pass SENTRY_CLIENT to each process but I am trying to avoid that as of now.
Also as this script is executed by celery worker I had configured sentry for celery and any exception till `pool.map()` is well caught by sentry.

Also I tried to print the `SENTRY_CLIENT.__dict__` and I got the valid items with correct values.
My issue is here that why SENTRY_CLIENT is not sending exceptions to sentry dashboard. May be I am missing something in configurations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally get the solution by some readings.
Sentry works on an async event based model and killing a process just after triggering sentry will not ensure the exception is reached to the servers. Hence we need to add a delay(10s), before killing the process in case of any exception to ensure sentry does it's job.

```
def process_data(data):
    from configurations import SENTRY_CLIENT
    try:
       s = data/0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
       print "Sentry must report this."
       import time
       SENTRY_CLIENT.captureException()
       time.sleep(10)

import multiprocessing
from billiard import Pool
POOL_SIZE=multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = Pool(POOL_SIZE)
data=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
pool.map(process_data, data)
pool.close()
pool.terminate()
```

Comment: Instead of using `time.sleep`, a synchronous transport can replace the default asynchronous one. See https://raven.readthedocs.io/en/stable/transports.html

Comment: synchronous transport is not implemented in the new Sentry SDK: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/125

Answer (score 2):

As PoloSoares [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173252/how-to-configure-sentry-to-send-exception-from-process-spawned-by-python-multipr#comment88017277_44216502), you should change a transport instead of adding any delay by sleep. Example of valid solution for 6.10.0 version of raven lib:

```python
import multiprocessing

from billiard import Pool
from raven import Client
from raven.transport.http import HTTPTransport

SENTRY_CLIENT = Client("dsn", transport=HTTPTransport)


def process_data(data):
    try:
        s = data / 0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Sentry must report this.")
        SENTRY_CLIENT.captureException()


POOL_SIZE = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = Pool(POOL_SIZE)
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
pool.map(process_data, data)
pool.close()
pool.terminate()
```

Comment: [New sentry-sdk lib](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python) has http transport by default https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/blob/master/sentry_sdk/transport.py#L226